# If a,b,c,d are chosen from the set {1,2,3,....,9}.The what is the minimum value of a/b+c/d.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

If $a,b,c,d$ are chosen from the set $\{1,2,3,....,9\}$, 
then what is the minimum value of $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} \ $?

I will show two workouts here....

1st workout

Let value of $a=1,b=9,c=2,d=8$.
Then  $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} = \frac{13}{36}$

And thus the minimum value.

2nd workout

using AM-GM inequality

$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac{a c}{b  d} }$

giving us the value $\frac{1}{ 3}$

Now one must see that $\frac{1}{3}$ lesser than $\frac{13}{36}$..

then what should be the correct answer to this problem

Comment: must $a,b,c,d$ take distinct value?

Comment: I edited your post to make it more readable, please check that it's still asking what you want.

Comment: Note that (1/9+2/8)-(2/9+1/8) = 1/8-1/9 > 0; so you know that at least 2/9+1/8 is smaller than your choice.

Answer (score 1):

We have to minimise $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} $. So we seek *minimise the numerator and maximise the denominator of individual fractions*.

Thus $(a,b) = (1,2)$ for minimum numerator. For $(c,d)$ we can have two cases $(8,9)$ or $(9,8)$. Check these two cases.

As shown in comment by Steven, $\frac{1}{9} + \frac{2}{8} > \frac{1}{8} + \frac{2}{9}$ by checking the difference.

Hence you have the minimum value as $\frac{1}{8} + \frac{2}{9} = \frac{25}{72}$

Comment: And by the way this was not even in the options

Comment: See the last line

Comment: sorry really didnt mean to type 72 it was 25/36

Comment: Well then they must be asking you to compare your options, which you haven't provided.